There is a seemingly infinite loop of reverse forwarding in kernel32.dll
I'm writing an x86 manual map injector for Windows 10.
When writing the code responsible for resolving imports, I found a function from kernel32.dll (windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll) called "SleepConditionVariableSRW", which is a forwarder to "api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.SleepConditionVariableSRW". The DLL I've been testing my injector with relies upon it and imports it from kernel32.dll.
When I load the module (from windows\syswow64\downlevel) and look at the exports, SleepConditionVariableSRW is again a forwarder, but to kernel32.dll again. I would understand if it was regular reverse forwarding and the API set forwarded to kernelbase.dll or something, but this just makes no sense to me.
The DLL I'm testing with importing the function from kernel32.dll:

kernel32.dll exporting the function as a forwarder to the API set:

The API set exporting the function as a forwarder back to kernel32.dll, which forwarded to the API set in the first place:

I looked at every copy of that API set across my entire drive, and checked the exports to see if any of them, even x64, forwarded that function to any module besides kernel32.dll. They did not.
I injected the DLL I've been testing with using LoadLibraryA and checked the references to the function, and it calls the SleepConditionVariableSRW from kernelbase.dll. How did the Windows image loader figure out what module it was in? I thought the forwarder name of a function would always contain the correct module to find the export in.

Consider renaming your question, it is not a loop. do you mean something like a circular dependency?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/apiindex/api-set-loader-operation

There is configuration data elsewhere which the loader uses to process API sets. I don't recall the specific implementation details but it's some kind of map that links an API set function to an API implementation (e.g. kernelbase.dll). If you want to handle these correctly you'll need to recognize an API set is being requested and parse the configuration yourself.

@Luke appreciate it, this led me to the answer which I left on this post

Windows\System32\ApiSetSchema.dll, as well as any modules defined at Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\ApiSetSchemaExtensions\, have a section called .apiset containing data that maps API Sets to their host modules. More info at https://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/win32/apisetschema/index.htm

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
